# Sitefinity and Embedded Google Map - How to center the Marker?

Tags: google-maps, sitefinity

I am trying to generate a Google map for my events in Sitefinity. I am using an embedded Google iframe code and I am using `<%# Eval("Street") %>` and `<%# Eval("City") %>` and `<%# Eval("State") %>` to pull the location of my events from my Sitefinity events custom fields to output html.

So my code looks like this:

```
<iframe width='500' height='240' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<%# Eval("Street") %>+<%# Eval("City") %>+<%# Eval("State") %>&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=<%# Eval("Street") %>+<%# Eval("City") %>+<%# Eval("State") %>&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=<%# Eval("Street") %>+<%# Eval("City") %>+<%# Eval("State") %>&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed&iwloc=near'></iframe>
```

Now the map is getting generate for the events and everything is working fine except the marker on the map is not getting centered.  What should I do to make the marker centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample HTML with three maps.  Make sure that the arguments from Sitefinity are returning what you expect by inspecting the HTML in Developer Tools.  Also make sure that there are spaces or commas between Address, City and state. Also if you are using Sitefinity 6 they have [Google Maps](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/google-maps) built in now.

```
   <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <iframe width='500' height='240' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=510 W Main St Fort Wayne IN&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=510 W Main St Fort Wayne IN&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=510 W Main St Fort Wayne IN&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed&iwloc=near'></iframe>
    <iframe width='500' height='240' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=1770 Apple Glen Blvd Fort Wayne IN&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=1770 Apple Glen Blvd Fort Wayne IN&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1770 Apple Glen Blvd Fort Wayne IN&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed&iwloc=near'></iframe>
    <iframe width='500' height='240' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed&iwloc=near'></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Using the Google Maps V3 API. Paste the javascript & map div inside the widget in sitefiniy, use your <%#Eval("address")%> as the string being passed to the GetLatLong() function

```
<html html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEYHERE&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var marker;
    var map;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        initialize();
    });

    function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8282, -98.5795),//US Center as Default
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
        GetLatLong("201 W Main St Fort Wayne IN");//Use your <%#Eval("Address")%> here Like
        //GetLatLong('<%#Eval("Street")%> <%#Eval("City")%> <%#Eval("State")%> ');
    }
    function GetLatLong(address){
        if (geocoder)
        {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results,status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    var l = results[0].geometry.location;
                    map.setCenter(l);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            map: map,
                            title: address
                            });
                }
                else
                {

                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px;width:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jon, Thanks. I double checked the generated code by inspecting the HTML in developer tool as you suggested.  The generated HTML looks good and when I test it as a HTML file, it works fine and the marker is centered.  The marker is just not getting centered in Sitefinity.  here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/faramarz/YxYGd/).  I am using Sitefinity 6 but the built-in map only works as a custom field when you use the custom module builder.  I want to do this for Events module which is an existing module and not custom.

Comment: Are you willing to use the Google Maps API (JavaScript)?

Comment: Jon, I'm getting back to this project after a long time, your solution works but I cannot replace the GetLatLong('201 W Main St Fort Wayne IN'); default address with <%#Eval("Address")%> or <%#Eval("Street")%> etc. I pasted the JavaScript at the bottom of my widget template and looks like the JS code is not understanding the C# Eval code when I do this: GetLatLong('<%#Eval("Street")%> <%#Eval("City")%> <%#Eval("State")%> ');

Comment: Make sure the Eval() is inside the item template.

Comment: +1 Jon. I created a var inside my itemtemplate for the Evals and passed them to GetLatLong() function and now it's working :)